# Is it possible to get type of current JSX tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

For example if I have something like:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={getStyle(component where this style belong to 'TouchableOpacity')}>
```

I want to pass to `getStyle` function component that call function.
If I pass `this.constructor.name` I get screen of component but don't know how to get `TouchableOpacity`.
I want to use it in generic way so I don't need to always write string of component.
Is this possible?

Comment: sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you add some context details? Trying to rely on (wrapped) component type looks against React flow to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know the component name or the class so you can pass it directly

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  style={getStyle(TouchableOpacity || 'TouchableOpacity')}
>
```

Your function `getStyle()` is **unable** to know your component and figure out it itself, because this function is called and done before your component is created.

More detailed statement `<TouchableOpacity>` - is actually call of function - so it can be replaced with `f1()`. And `getStyle()` may be replaced with `f2()`.

So you are asking about, how to know in the function `f2()` which function uses its result (the result of `f2()`) as param. In the next statement:

```js
f1(f2())
```

So the answer is **no**.

However if you pass as mentioned above `getStyle(TouchableOpacity)` you can get the tag name or display-name of component like this:

```js
function getStyle(component) {
  console.log('tag name:', component.type.name)
  console.log('display name:', component.type.displayName)
}

getStyle(TouchableOpacity)
```